# Postgres UUID correlation workaround

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, statistics

I have a table with a UUIDv4 field `owner`. The table has 10s of millions of rows, but only a few thousand unique owners. Owners typically create/update their rows in one burst, so their tuples are decently clustered on disk.

However, because the owner IDs are randomly generated, PG reports near 0 correlation for the `owner` field. I think this results in more bitmap index scans, which prevent pipelined sorts/groups on some queries.

Short of changing the field to use a sequence (which would add some meaningful complexity since owner IDs are generated externally), is there a way to tell PG "this field clusters on disk"?

---

**Update**

I wasn't able to reproduce the sort/group issue, but have another query that I think is suffering from this same problem:

```sql
-- Owner has jobs; jobs have tasks. Count total tasks for owner
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM tasks
 WHERE job_id IN (SELECT id FROM jobs WHERE owner_id = $1);
```

```
-- explain analyze was taking too long so had to use plain explain
 Finalize Aggregate  (cost=17555100.96..17555100.97 rows=1 width=8)
   ->  Gather  (cost=17555100.74..17555100.95 rows=2 width=8)
         Workers Planned: 2
         ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=17554100.74..17554100.75 rows=1 width=8)
               ->  Hash Join  (cost=771048.51..17552217.68 rows=753226 width=0)
                     Hash Cond: (tasks.job_id = jobs.id)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on tasks  (cost=0.00..15282822.27 rows=120838427 width=16)
                     ->  Hash  (cost=767196.77..767196.77 rows=221579 width=16)
                           ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on jobs  (cost=21117.80..767196.77 rows=221579 width=16)
                                 Recheck Cond: (owner_id = $1)
                                 ->  Bitmap Index Scan on jobs_owner_id_status_is_test_9158deef_idx  (cost=0.00..21062.41 rows=221579 width=0)
                                       Index Cond: (owner_id = $1)
```

```sql
-- relevant indexes
CREATE INDEX tasks_job_id_bb29335c ON tasks(job_id);
CREATE INDEX jobs_owner_id_status_is_test_9158deef_idx ON (owner_id, status, is_test);
```

The `jobs` (ca 10M rows) table naturally clusters by `owner_id`, and the `tasks` table (ca 100M rows) naturally clusters by `job_id`. I would've therefore hoped for this query to use normal index scans for both `jobs` and `tasks` since most I/O will be sequential, but instead it's using a bitmap index scan for `jobs` and then a full seq scan for `tasks`

Comment: How do you know this is a problem? Are you queries slow? If yes, then please [edit] your question and add the slow query and its [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: What is a pipelined sort?  Sort needs to read all of its input before it can generate any of its output.

Comment: You could `CLUSTER` the table. Or perhaps, if there are few enough owners, you could use partitioning.